# Custom slider curve for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making an iOS app for sound synthesis. And I need a custom slider by which user can adjust the sound frequency. The slider has unique design - wave form (an example is shown in the picture).

[image: Custom slider]

How to make slider with complex curve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

12pm - I can't think of any immediately obvious, simple, way to do this in iOS. I'd look around for a package and if you're lucky there will be one!  Otherwise it's just a case of plain hard programming.

You may possibly have to use beziers ([Find the tangent of a point on a cubic bezier curve](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4089443/294884)) to define the travel path.  Or maybe, "simply" two half-circles.

From there use a "normal" slider concept to get the X position of the finger, **but just position the "y" value of the red ball, per your equations**.  That will work OK.

---

For a better approach (**I doubt it will be necessary**), the NEXT more complicated approach is: ALSO note the Y value of the finger.  WHEN THE FINGER IS NEAR the "difficult" parts", THEN INSTEAD consider the Y value.  Do you see what I mean?

Finally the "ultimate solution" .. you need to get in to finding the "closest point on a curve" (i.e., give some point). This is classic game programming math. So follow something like

http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/51/83/79/PDF/Xiao-DiaoChen2007c.pdf

Check out any of these classic books for that type of thing

[http://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Programming-Computer-Graphics-Edition/dp/1435458869](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1435458869)

[http://www.amazon.com/Real-Time-Collision-Detection-Interactive-Technology/dp/1558607323](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558607323)

However, IMO it would be "thoughtless engineering" .. .solution "A" or "B" is typically perfect!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Joe Blow. If I understand you right, only X coordinate of the finger will influence on slider position. But I need  that user can change slider value only by moving finger by the direction of yellow curve.

Comment: It's hard to explain, but trust me, it will work, fairly well, 100%. Mathematically, you have only a 1:1 mapping, so it's 100% safe to measure ONLY the X position of the user's finger.  There are more complicated solutions, but - quite simply - until you perfectly implement this solution, you won't be able to implement the more complex solutions.  I hope it helps!

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much, Joe. I've done this in 6 lines of code. I use two half-circles to define the path, like you wrote. And calculate only Y position by simple formula:
`double multiplier = 2 * M_PI / lenght * (-1);
double angle = (coordinateX - minX) * multiplier;
float coordinateY = diameter * sin(angle) + shiftY;`

Comment: It's nothing, i just wish I could help more.  Right-on with tour formula.  Check my edit also ....